# Cells accept only specific values written

Tags: excel, vba

I just started using vba and I was wondering if I can get some guidance here. I am trying to set the range a1:a50 to accept only numbers written like this: i.e. 111.111.111 or 231.432.212. I set this by using %%%.%%%.%%% as I read that % is defined as a number in VBA.

However, using this format %%%.%%%.%%% does not do the job. Can anyone guide me to fix this if it is possible? Must appreciated.

```
Dim cell As Range
     Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell In Target
         If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range("a1:a50")) Is Nothing Then
           If Not cell.Value = %%%.%%%.%%% Then
               cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)

       Else

           cell.Interior.Color = RGB(1000, 1000, 1000)
           End If
        End If
   Next cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RegEx to test the cell value. You could run the following macro to see how it works.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) for how to set up RegEx in Excel.

```
Sub Test_Reg()
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}"
'Note: if you want to exact match 9 numbers with two dots, 
'      then use strPattern = "^[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}$"
strInput1 = "111.111.111"
strInput2 = "1234.1234.1234"
strInput3 = "12.12.12"
strInput4 = "12a.12a.12a"


    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With
    MsgBox (regEx.Test(strInput1))
    MsgBox (regEx.Test(strInput2))
    MsgBox (regEx.Test(strInput3))
    MsgBox (regEx.Test(strInput4))

End Sub
```

Then your code could be modified like this:

```
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}"
'Note: if you want to exact match 9 numbers with two dots, 
'      then use strPattern = "^[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}$"
With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With
Dim cell As Range
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     For Each cell In Target
         If Not Application.Intersect(cell, Range("a1:a50")) Is Nothing Then
           If (NOT regEx.Test(cell.Value)) Then
               cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)

       Else

           cell.Interior.Color = RGB(1000, 1000, 1000)
           End If
        End If
   Next cell
   Application.EnableEvents = True
```